# Client returning undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I have a custom event handler class where I have the following

```
public client: NullClient;
public path: string;

constructor(client: NullClient, path: string){
   this.client = client;
   this.path = path;
}

    loadAll() {
        for(const type of readdirSync(this.path)) {
            for(const file of readdirSync(`${this.path}/${type}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'))) {
                const props = require(`${this.path}/${type}/${file}`).default;
                const listener: Listener = new props();
                listener.client = this.client;

                if(listener instanceof Listener) {
                    const emitter = this.emitters.get(listener.emitter);
                    if(!this.isEmitter(emitter)) throw new Error(`INVALID EMITTER!`);

                    listener.type === 'on' ? emitter?.on(listener.event, listener.exec) : emitter?.once(listener.event, listener.exec);
                    return listener;
                } else {
                    throw new Error('INVALID TYPE!');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do here is set `listener.client` as the client passed by `this.client` but there's 2 issues I'm coming accross

1. console.log(this.client) in the handler class **ALWAYS** returns an incomplete ClientUser object, where Client#user is **ALWAYS** null
2. Trying to call `this.client` in any of my events **ALWAYS** returns undefined.

My listener class is:

```
import NullClient from '../../lib/NullClient';

export default class Listener {
    public emitter: string;
    public event: string;
    public type?: 'on' | 'once';
    public client!: NullClient;

    constructor(options: ListenerOptions) {
        this.emitter = options.emitter;
        this.event = options.event;
        this.type = options.type || 'on';
    }

    exec(...args: any) {
        throw new Error('EXEC FUNCTION NOT IMPLEMENTED! Your listener is missing an \'exec\' function');
    }
}

interface ListenerOptions {
    emitter: string;
    event: string;
    type?: 'on' | 'once';
}
```

Extending off of this class then trying to call `this.client` returns undefined, anyone know what I can do or change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `listener.exec` to the `emitter` which makes `listener.exec` a callback. When it executes, its `this` will not work as you expect. Callbacks must be bound in order for `this` to work correctly.

Try this instead

```
emitter?.on(listener.event, listener.exec.bind(listener));
```

This way, when `exec` runs, `this` inside it will be bound to `listener` so accessing `this.client` will be equivalent to `listener.client`